# Java GBK enconding and PHP

Tags: java, php, char

The following code is a PHP one I need to convert to Java to write it to a socket connection

```
$info = chr(6).chr(0).chr(255).chr(255).'info';
```

On PHP it works perfectly  with this code

```
$Socket = fsockopen($this->Host, $this->Port, $errno, $errstr, 5);
fwrite($Socket, chr(6).chr(0).chr(255).chr(255).'info');
```

I tried doing this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        char a = 6;
        char b = 0;
        char c = 255;


        try {

            Socket test = new Socket("shadowcores.twifysoft.net", 7171);
            BufferedWriter write = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(test.getOutputStream()));

            write.write(Character.toString(a) + "." + Character.toString(b) + "." + Character.toString(c) + "." +  Character.toString(c)  + "." +  "info");
            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(test.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println(read.read());
            test.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

With no success because I should be getting some information from the server after writing that message to it
How can I convert that PHP string to Java one?

Comment: Why are there dots in your Java code? They're not in the PHP version...

Comment: Was just me trying to emulate it..

Comment: But the PHP version doesn't output a dot. The dot operator in PHP is string concatenation, which as you've found is `+` in Java.